# PostGIS - tiling vector layer

Tags: qgis, postgis, vector, tiles

I have a height isoline vector layer covering a large area, but most of the time, I am only working on a small part of it, so all kind of handling of the data goes slowly. Are there any ways to make a tiled layer so I just load the tiles I need? The layer is stored in PostGIS with a spatial index and I am using QGIS when working on the layer.

I know I could create a grid in QGIS, then do a split with lines to get what I want, but that would create a new layer, I would prefer if there is a way, either in QGIS or bya query in PostGIS to update the existing layer.

Comment: Do you have a spatial index? How large are the objects, i.e., would a bounding-box query filter almost all of them out?

Comment: QGIS pulls data from PG via viewport bbox. An index helps, given the geometries are small enough for the filtering to make sense. Best option for speed is to dump those lines into smaller (e.g. 2-vertex) segments, as contours tend to be intrinsically long.

Comment: PostGIS already tiles the raster, according to the parameters at creation. Please [Edit]  the Question to contain your load procedure.

Comment: @Vince, My issue is with a vector layer, not raster.